# AES encryption with Javascript using cryptojs same as Java - AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

Tags: javascript, angular, cryptojs

I am using AES encryption in Java and want to do same in Javascript/Typescript using cryptojs.

I am trying below Javascript code but both are returning different results.

**Java Code**

```
 String sKey = 'MySecureKeyText1';
 String _text = "ValuetoEncrypt";

 byte key[] = sKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
 KeySpec aKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"); 

 MessageDigest hashMD5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
 hashMD5.update(sKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));
 byte[] ivbytes = hashMD5.digest();
 IvParameterSpec IV = new IvParameterSpec(ivbytes, 0, ivbytes.length); 

 Cipher mCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
 mCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, (Key) aKeySpec, IV);

 string ciphertext = mCipher.doFinal(_text.getBytes());
 ciphertext = ByteToHex(ciphertext); // .CAAFD9C519C23E91A4B58D158ECA5462
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
this.encrypt('ValuetoEncrypt', 'MySecureKeyText1');
encrypt(value : string, key:string) : string{
    let ivHash = cryptoJS.MD5(key).toString();
    let cipher = this.cipher(value, key, ivHash);
    return cipher.ciphertext.toString(); // 5a78aa6905208aa6fa63d1d452ea482e
  }

cipher(value, key, iv) {
    const cipher = cryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, key, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: cryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        keySize: 128,
        padding: cryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    return cipher;
  }
```

**Issue Resolved**

Fixed this issue by converting key into byte array using `cryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse` before passing for ecryption.

As per the [crypto-js](https://github.com/jakubzapletal/crypto-js#block-modes-and-padding) documentation if we pass key in string format then they use it to derive an actual key and iv, If we pass in word array then it will use actual value we sent.

```
this.encrypt('ValuetoEncrypt', 'MySecureKeyText1');
encrypt(value: string, key: string): string {
    const ivMd5Hash = cryptoJS.MD5(cryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key));
    const cipher = this.cipher(cryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(value), cryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), ivMd5Hash);

    return cipher.ciphertext.toString();
  }

  cipher(value, key, iv): any {
    const cipher = cryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, key, {
      iv: iv,
      mode: cryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      keySize: 128,
      padding: cryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    return cipher;
  }
```

**Note**:- It is better to use their default behaviour as it generates different key every time that will be more secure But in my case it was requirement to use fix format.

Comment: You use PKCS7 padding in the JS code and PKCS5 padding in Java code. I have little practical experience with low-level encryption code, but that's got to be wrong. **Edit:** Apparentyl I'm wrong. [When Java says "PCKS5" it really means "PKCS7" in this case](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding) ...

Comment: Java only provides PKCS#5 padding, but it is the same as PKCS#7 padding.They are interchangeable for the common block ciphers like AES and DES. So, It seems this problem is not related to PKCS#5 or PKCS#7 padding. Anyway thanks for your response.